# MySql Integer to Floating Point Expression

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to echo out a FLOAT value like when i used my calculator but the output is an integer.
how to get the float output?

Explanation below :

here are the values :

```
user_rate=350
user_overtime=3


user_rate/8*user_overtime AS overtimetotal

current output is  = 131
expected output is = 131.25
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are performing integer arithmetic (which results in truncation of the float part). Instead use:

```
user_rate/8.0 * user_overtime AS overtimetotal
```

this will promote your expression to floating point.